# How to modify this R code to get the result unordered? Seats allocation

Tags: r

I've found an R package, SiencesPo, to allocate seats proportionally to votes using different methods.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SciencesPo/versions/1.4.1/topics/HighestAverages

I'm interested in the function HighestAverages, but the result provided is a frequency table reordering the output depending on the number of seats allocated to each party.

I would like to just get a vector keeping the original result.

The reason is because I want to apply it in many different regions and then aggregate the results.

For example

```
party=c("White", "Yellow", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Pink")
votes=c(16000,47000, 15900, 12000,  6000,   3100)
HighestAverages(party, votes, seats = 10, method="dh")
```

produces this result:

```
-------------------------
 Party   Seats   % Seats 
------- ------- ---------
Yellow     5       50    
  Red      2       20    
 White     2       20    
 Green     1       10    
 Blue      0        0    
 Pink      0        0
```

I woull like to keep the original order, just

```
-------------------------
 Party   Seats   % Seats 
------- ------- ---------
 White     2       20    
Yellow     5       50    
  Red      2       20    
 Green     1       10    
 Blue      0        0    
 Pink      0        0
```

Or better just a vector:

```
 c(2,5,2,1,0,0)
```

How could I modify the code?
Or how could modify the output to get the one I need?

```
HighestAverages <-   function(parties = NULL, votes = NULL, 
    seats = NULL, method = c("dh"), threshold = 0) {
    .ratio <- votes / sum(votes)
    .votes <- ifelse(.ratio < threshold, 0, votes)

    # To deal with  NULL party labels
    if (is.null(parties)) {      parties <- replicate(length(votes),paste(sample(LETTERS, 3,replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))     }

    # Define Quotient, I only need "dh"
    switch(
      method,
      dh = {  divisor.vec <- seq(from = 1,by = 1, length.out = seats) ; method.name <- c("d'Hondt") }
    )

    # ratio = as.vector(sapply(votes, function(x) x / sum(votes)))
    .temp <- data.frame(parties = rep(parties, each = seats), scores = as.vector(sapply(.votes, function(x) x / divisor.vec)))

    out <- with(.temp, (parties[order(-scores)][1:seats]))  #
    output <- freq(out, digits = 3, perc = TRUE)

    # Political diversity indices
    ENP_votes <- 1 / sum(.ratio ^ 2)
    ENP_seats <- 1 / sum((output$Freq / sum(output$Freq)) ^ 2)
    LSq_index <- sqrt(0.5 * sum(((( votes / sum(votes) ) * 100) - ((output$Freq / sum(output$Freq)) * 100  )) ^ 2))

    .shorten <- function(x, n)       cat("Divisors:", x[1:n], "...", "\n")
    cat("Method:", method.name, "\n")
    .shorten(round(divisor.vec, 2), 4)
    cat(paste("ENP:", round(ENP_votes, 2), "(After):", round(ENP_seats, 2)), "\n")
    cat(paste("Gallagher Index: ", round(LSq_index, 2)), "\n \n")
    names(output) <- c("Party", "Seats", "\u0025 Seats")

    # output <- output[ order(output[,2], decreasing = TRUE),]
    class(output) <- c("SciencesPo", class(output))
    attr(output, "scpo.type") <- "Standard"
    return(output)
  }

}
```

I guess the important lines are

```
out <- with(.temp, (parties[order(-scores)][1:seats]))  #
output <- freq(out, digits = 3, perc = TRUE)
```

but I don't know how to modify them properly without side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply `str()` to the outcome of `HighestAverages` function, then you will know that it is a subclass of a data.frame.
So you can modify it just you do with a data.frame.

```
library(SciencesPo)

party=c("White", "Yellow", "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Pink")
votes=c(16000,47000, 15900, 12000,  6000,   3100)
x <- HighestAverages(party, votes, seats = 10, method="dh")

str(x)

x$Party <- factor(x$Party, levels=party)
x <- x[order(x$Party),]
rownames(x) <- NULL   
x
```

Comment: The reason it works is because parties are factors?
I must check it.  Would you also know how to modify directly the code? avoiding then to reorder twice?

Comment: Then, in one line  x[order(factor(x$Party, levels=party)), "Seats"]   Any reason why this could not work in some situation?

Comment: I think that works too.  If you want to change your function directly, then you perhaps need to add a similar `order` function at the end.

Comment: It's a different question but do you know how to include blank votes ( protest votes), that account for the total number of valid votes but don't geat any seat.

Comment: Hmm, does that impact the calculation of the sheet allocation?

Comment: Yes, sometimes, I think it happens when you use a threeshold.  Anyway I've modified the code to to it by replacing sum(votes) with  validvotes.

Comment: I've seen the code uses a modified freq() function from the same package.  I think I'm going to replace it with base::table() and modify the code accordingly to remove dependencies on external packages.

Comment: Do you think is the same if I use as.vector(table(out)[parties])
 inside the HighestAverages.R code?